# No me detecta en codigo ascii en el caracter que quiero

Tags: c, ascii

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 1000;

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char caracteres[1000];

    file = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
    
     if(file==NULL) {
        printf("No se puede abrir el archivo\n");
    } else {
        int i=0;
        char c;
        while((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            if(c>48 && c<=57){
            caracteres[i]=c; 
            printf("%c", caracteres[i]); 
            i++; 
            }
            else{
                break;
            }       
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

El txt contiene 1 2 3 H 4, solo me guarda el 1 y no sigue. He probado a poner la condicion dentro del bucle pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás ejecutando un `break` cuando encuentras algo que no es un número, es decir, estás saliendo del bucle y dejas de leer caracteres. En el archivo tienes espacios, por lo que el programa lee el 1, luego lee un espacio, y sale del bucle.

Si lo que quieres es leer solo los números, deberías tener el código de esta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 1000;

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    char caracteres[1000];

    file = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
    
     if(file==NULL){
        printf("No se puede abrir el archivo\n");
    }
    else{
        int i=0;
        char c;
        while((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF){
            if(c>48 && c<=57){
            caracteres[i]=c; 
            printf("%c", caracteres[i]);
            i++; 

            }

            
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Si te fijas, he eliminado la sentencia `else` para que no salga del programa  y continue con la lectura de caracteres.

**EDIT**

Si lo que quieres es que no tenga en cuenta los espacios en blanco, debes tenerlo en cuenta en el `else`:

```
else {
   if(c==32){ 
      continue; 
   }else{ 
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Buenas entiendo la solucion pero el break era para que una vez dentro del archivo encontrase algo distinto a un numero parase el bucle. Esto es debido a que una vez encuentre algo distinto a un numero, debo realizar una funcion con la cadena de numeros que haya quedado hasta ese momento

Comment: Entiendo, entonces como expliqué en la pregunta, se para porque está encontrando un espacio en blanco, por eso se queda solo con el 1.

Comment: He editado la pregunta para que no tenga en cuenta los espacios en blanco @piinduu